# Programmatically Stop an Azure function and start it back again

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an azure function that reads messages from a service bus queue and sends a request to an API with the message. This works fine.

Sometimes the API may be unreachable due to factors not in our control. Is there a way to stop the Azure function from recieving updates from the queue or stop execution altogether till it is restarted ideally via an api call or via an environment variable ?

Comment: I don't think so, since it is built on top of the Web Jobs SDK (if you are familiar with that functionality)

Comment: you can stop the webapp that's hosting the function app. well, that's how it was working earlier. don't think it was changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use an environment variable. For example, if you have an environment variable named `TIMER_DISABLED`, you can reference that setting in the `disabled` function property like so:

```
{
  "disabled": "TIMER_DISABLED",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "*/5 * * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

The function will then only be enabled if the app setting value is truthy, e.g. equal to 1 or "true".

Comment: what would be great is to see your answer linked to the Functions documentation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings